# How to show in Active elements if my check box is checked?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a problem solving this query. In my where clause I have a logic that gives me just active fields from my table. But I want if my checkbox is checked to give me active and inactive elements. How can I solve that? Is it possible to put cfif around where clause or some other way? Here is my query:

```
SELECT Date, Name, Time, Active
       Case when Active = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Active
FROM City
<cfif form.ActiveCheck GT 0>
WHERE Active = 0
</cfif>
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

and here is my check box code:

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="ActiveCheck" id="ActiveCheck" value="0" unchecked>All<br>
```

Comment: can you post what your query would look like? something like `where active = 0 or inactive = 0` ?

Comment: (Edit) If I understand correctly, the field names and values do not seem match their purpose. You said *"if my checkbox is checked to give me active and inactive elements"* - yet the field is named "ActiveCheck" and the label is "All"? Why not just have a single field named "ShowActiveOnly". When it is checked, return only active records. Otherwise it will return all records ie `<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "ShowActiveOnly")>WHERE Active = 1</cfif>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't want to filter by the active column in your query when the checkbox is ticked? To do that you'd do something like:

```
<cfquery name="myQ">
    SELECT Date, Name, Time, Active
        Case when Active = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Active
    FROM City
    <cfif !structKeyExists(form, "ActiveCheck")>
        <!--- checkbox is not ticked so just get inactive --->
        WHERE Active = <cfqueryparam value="0" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    </cfif>
    ORDER BY Date DESC
</cfquery>

....

<input type="Checkbox" name="ActiveCheck" id="ActiveCheck" value="0">All<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This similar to John's answer, but I don't like `<cfif>` inside of `<cfquery>`. I want the DB server to have as few query plans as possible. **Note:** IIF() is an old-school approach.

```
<cfquery name="myQ">
DECLARE @Active bit = <cfqueryparam value="#IIF(stuctkeyExists(form, 'activecheck'), 1, 0)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">

SELECT Date, Name, Time, Active,
    Case when Active = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Active
FROM City
WHERE @ActiveCheck = 0 
OR   (@ActiveCheck = 1 AND Active = 1)
ORDER BY Date DESC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I like IIF even less ;-)  Simpler to use cfparam instead.

Comment: Could use a ternary operator instead of the IIF. `structKeyExists(form, "activecheck") ? 1 : 0`

Comment: My main concern was getting rid of the `<cfif>` inside of the `<cfquery>`

Comment: Understood. Though two cached plans versus one would not be that big a deal. Efficiency of the plans would be more relevant. Assuming there even is a significant difference. I do not know, I did not test it.

Comment: Both answers are correct. I have them tested. What I did, I put onClick function in my checkbox, around checked I put <cfif ActiveP EQ 1>checked</cfif>. Before that I created cfparm and set default=1. In java script I did:if (obj.checked){
   location.href="Test.cfm?ActiveP=1"
  }else{
   location.href="Test.cfm?ActiveP=0"
  }

Comment: This answer only works with sql server.  The rdbms was not specified.  Even with sql server, this approach looks like it would be slower than necessary.